# Linear approximation of time dilation. In what point is it?

Tags: differentiation, time-dilation, approximations

I have watched a video about linear approximation and there was an example, exactly here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSAA0akmPEU&feature=youtu.be&list=PL590CCC2BC5AF3BC1&t=32m50s about linear approximation of time dilation. I have started to count and this is the result:
$$ f(t,v) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$
$$ \frac{df(t,v)}{dv} = \frac{tv}{c^2(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$
so combining those two things into linear approximation I have:
$$ f(t,v) \approx f(t,v_0) + f(t,v_0)'(v-v_0) $$
then putting real bodies of functions:
$$ f(t,v) \approx \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2}}} + \frac{tv_0}{c^2(1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}(v-v_0)  \approx \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2}}} - \frac{tv_0^2}{c^2(1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{tv_0v}{c^2(1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$
then I can imagine that: 
$$ v_0 << c $$
So I think that I can do something like that:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2}}} \approx 1 $$
then
$$ f(t,v) \approx t - \frac{tv_0^2}{c^2} + \frac{tv_0v}{c^2} $$
and then compering to result from video it should be equal to 
$$ T' = T(1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}) $$
but unfortunately it is not equal. Can somebody tell me what mistakes I have made? What is wrong with my reasoning? I will be really appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You effectively killed $f(t,v)$ when you set

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_0^2}{c^2}}} \approx 1$$

The result can be obtained much simpler by using known approximation rules

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}} \approx\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{v^2}{2c^2}}\approx 1+\dfrac{v^2}{2c^2}$$